# High GPU usage before starting X-Server

Tags: x-server, ati, gpu, amd-graphics

When starting my Debian Jessie, my GPU (ATI 5770) uses a lot of power (it is getting hot), although I am only displaying the terminal. Then, if I start an x-server, the GPU cools down again, also the system's power usage is cut approximatly in half. I am using the `fglrx`-driver. What might be running on the GPU? Is power safe mode deactivated or what is the problem?